# How to interpret the feature importance in decision trees

Tags: python

I am currently working on a simple data science project. I am trying my hands out on the decision trees classifier.. I have come to the point where I want to know the important features in the data set. After printing out the important features I get an array of values which I cannot quite interpret. 
So how do interpret those values?

Comment: features depends on data and context of the problem and interpretation depends on the problem, try to give more details and be specific.

Comment: I would like to know generally, how you would identify a particular feature from the array output when the feature importance attribute is accessed.